# Resgatar dados para criação de tabelas dinâmicas e gráficos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

tudo bem?

Estou com uma dúvida aqui em um projeto que peguei, não sou expert em banco de dados e muito menos em php, estou em fase de aprendizado.
Eu preciso de uma função para coletar alguns dados do banco de uma maneira que eu possa usá-los para criar algumas tabelas e graficos.

Deveria ficar mais ou menos assim a tabela:
[image: Tabela final]

Mas ela tá trazendo os dados assim:
[image: Tabela Nutella]

Preciso que os dados seja listados da maneira mostrada na primeira tabela, e depois preciso fazer a soma correspondente ao mês, pra poder gerar um gráfico. Não reparem no gráfico, mas apenas na marcação do círculo em vermelho que é o que preciso no momento:
[image: Dados mensagem com gráfico]

Existem duas tabelas para se trabalhar com esses dados. Uma é a tabela de fontes, que seria onde a pessoa conseguiu o contato (google, whatsapp, panfleto, etc).
A outra tabela, seria a tabela de cadastro, que contém a "data de cadastro" e o "ID" da fonte do contato.

Meu código está da seguinte maneira:

Model

```
function total_fontes() {       

    $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS total');
    $this->db->from('clientes cl');
    $this->db->join('fontes ft', 'ft.id_fonte = cl.fontes_id_fonte');

    $query = $this->db->get();  

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $val) {
        return $val['total']; 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {

    $data = array(
        'page_title' => 'Gráficos',
        'show_clientes' => $this->mdl_clientes->get_datas(), //busca de datas com group_by
        'show_fontes' => $this->mdl_fontes->get_ordem_alfabetica(),//busca fontes e ordena alfabeticamente
        'fontes_quantidades' => $this->mdl_fontes->total_fontes(),//busca o total de fontes por dia (nao funciona)
    );

    $flash_msg = $this->session->flashdata('flash_message');
    if (isset($flash_msg) && !empty($flash_msg)) {
        $data['flash'] = $flash_msg;
    }

    $this->load->view('graficos/vwGraficos.php', $data);

}
```

View (sem formatação, estou buscando primeiro conseguir listar):

```
<table border="1">

    <?php if($show_fontes != FALSE) : ?>

            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>

                <?php foreach($show_fontes as $fnt) : ?>

                    <td>
                        <?= $fnt->titulo_fonte; ?>
                    </td>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>    

            <?php if($show_clientes != FALSE) : ?>

                <?php foreach($show_clientes as $clnt) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?= $clnt->data_registro; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?= $fontes_quantidades; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Se puderem me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Comment: Para trabalhar com banco de dados você pode utilizar PDO ou mysqli, mas recomendo utilizar PDO

Comment: Eu não posso te ajudar na parte do sql. Não entendi bem qual a consulta que você quer fazer. Mas quanto a parte em CodeIgniter, você está retornando a função total_fontes dentro de um loop - o que não faria sentido ainda que você quisesse retornar somente o primeiro valor. Depois, na view, você repete esse mesmo valor em todas as linhas, resultando no seu 2640 repetido na coluna facebook empreendimentos.

Comment: Eu preciso realizar uma consulta na tabela de clientes, e verificar quantos contatos por dia foram realizados através de panfletos, google, facebook, whatsapp, etc. Na tabela "fontes" estão os tipos de contato que pode ser cadastrados pelo cliente ou removidos, e na tabela clientes tem uma coluna com o ID dessas fontes. Daí precisaria de uma consulta que retornasse a quantidade de contatos de cada tipo de fonte, separados por data. Acho que baguncei um pouco a explicação mas é basicamente isso.

Comment: Acho que entendi. A consulta está errada. Count(*) retorna um unico valor que é a  quantidade de linhas na tabela. O que você precisa é (se e somente se o seu db->join() estiver correto) é um SELECT *, para selecionar todos os dados(O resultado é uma matriz). Você tem um problema na view tambêm. Para prreencher todos os dados da tabela, a solução provavelmente vai ter um loop dentro de um loop. Isso é relativamente trabalhoso. Vai demorar algumas horas. Mas, primeiro acerta a consulta ao banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi, valeu a dica, deu uma luz enorme agora pra o que to fazendo. Obrigado,